# can i add a gitlab ci job to trigger a chain build?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i'd like to create a gitlab ci pipeline that will allow me to either trigger individual jobs, or run all of those manually triggered jobs in sequence if i choose to.

To make things easier, here is a diagram

[image]

Job1,2,3,4 and `run-all` have a `when: manual` added in them, so i can go in and trigger one of them when i want.

What im after is that when i trigger `run-all`, all the jobs will fire up and run (and will ignore the `when: manual`).

I'd rather not go into dynamic pipelines and use a native feature of gitlab-ci but im not sure how to search for that.